# Rsyslog template with RELP

Tags: rsyslog, ubuntu-20.04

I am trying to send logs to remote system with this configuration on client:

```
module(load="imjournal" StateFile="imjournal.state")
module(load="omrelp")

template(name="FileFormat" type="list") {
        property(name="timereported" dateFormat="rfc3339")
        constant(value=" ")
        property(name="hostname")
        constant(value=" ")
        property(name="syslogfacility-text")
        constant(value=" ")
        property(name="syslogseverity-text")
        constant(value=" ")
        property(name="app-name")
        constant(value=" PID ")
        property(name="procid")
        constant(value=" ")
        property(name="msgid")
        constant(value=" ")
        property(name="structured-data")
        constant(value=" ")
        property(name="msg")
        constant(value=" ")
        constant(value="\n")
}

kern.*                                                  action(type="omfile"  file="/var/log/kern.log" template="FileFormat")
*.info;mail.none;authpriv.none;cron.none                action(type="omfile"  file="/var/log/messages" template="FileFormat")
authpriv.*                                              action(type="omfile"  file="/var/log/secure" template="FileFormat")
mail.*                                                  action(type="omfile"  file="/var/log/maillog" template="FileFormat")
cron.*                                                  action(type="omfile"  file="/var/log/cron" template="FileFormat")
*.emerg                                                 :omusrmsg:*
uucp,news.crit                                          action(type="omfile"  file="/var/log/spooler" template="FileFormat")
local7.*                                                action(type="omfile"  file="/var/log/boot.log" template="FileFormat")


*.* action(type="omrelp"  target="10.0.20.30" port="2514" template="FileFormat")
```

Locally, logs are well formated with all fields required especially for date (2022-07-26T07:06:25.723077+00:00)

Remotely all fields are present but impossible to get a well date formated (Jul 26 08:58:34 )

I cannot handle why

If i try to add options in the template  on client side for date customization like

```
property(name="timereported" dateFormat="rfc3339" position.from="1" position.to="23")
```

Logs are no longer sent remotely

If i modify the action item without using template formating like :

```
*.* action(type="omrelp"  target="10.0.20.30" port="2514")
```

I have much more log files remotely.

I can't understand theses behaviors. Does someone already had theses issues ?

Answer (score 0):

Finally found it:

Template has to be applied on rsyslog configuration on destination server (and not on source and it works

Here comes a client configuration :

```
#Loading module for logs export with RELP Protocol
module(load="imjournal" StateFile="imjournal.state") # File to store the position in the journal
module(load="omrelp")


#Log Format Template as specified in RFC5424
template(name="FileFormat" type="list") {
        property(name="timereported" dateFormat="rfc3339" position.from="1" position.to="23")
        constant(value=" ")
        property(name="hostname")
        constant(value=" ")
        property(name="syslogfacility-text")
        constant(value=" ")
        property(name="syslogseverity-text")
        constant(value=" ")
        property(name="app-name")
        constant(value=" PID ")
        property(name="procid")
        constant(value=" ")
        property(name="msgid")
        constant(value=" ")
        property(name="structured-data")
        constant(value=" ")
        property(name="msg")
        constant(value=" ")
        constant(value="\n")
}




#Local Logging with templating
kern.*                                                  action(type="omfile"  file="/var/log/kern.log" template="FileFormat")
*.info;mail.none;authpriv.none;cron.none                action(type="omfile"  file="/var/log/messages" template="FileFormat")
authpriv.*                                              action(type="omfile"  file="/var/log/secure" template="FileFormat")
mail.*                                                  action(type="omfile"  file="/var/log/maillog" template="FileFormat")
cron.*                                                  action(type="omfile"  file="/var/log/cron" template="FileFormat")
daemon.*                                                action(type="omfile"  file="/var/log/daemon.log" template="FileFormat")
syslog.*                                                action(type="omfile"  file="/var/log/syslog.log" template="FileFormat")
user.*                                                  action(type="omfile"  file="/var/log/user.log" template="FileFormat")
*.emerg                                                 :omusrmsg:*
uucp,news.crit                                          action(type="omfile"  file="/var/log/spooler" template="FileFormat")
local7.*                                                action(type="omfile"  file="/var/log/boot.log" template="FileFormat")


#Export all systems logs to centralized server
*.*  :omrelp:$Destination_server:2514
```

And configuration on destination server :

```
#Load Modules for centralized syslog reception
module(load="imrelp")
module(load="imtcp")
module(load="imudp")
input(type="imrelp" port="2514" maxDataSize="10k")
input(type="imtcp" port="514" )
input(type="imudp" port="514")

#Log Format Template as specified in RFC5424
template(name="FileFormat" type="list") {
        property(name="timereported" dateFormat="rfc3339" position.from="1" position.to="23")
        constant(value=" ")
        property(name="hostname")
        constant(value=" ")
        property(name="syslogfacility-text")
        constant(value=" ")
        property(name="syslogseverity-text")
        constant(value=" ")
        property(name="app-name")
        constant(value=" PID ")
        property(name="procid")
        constant(value=" ")
        property(name="msgid")
        constant(value=" ")
        property(name="structured-data")
        constant(value=" ")
        property(name="msg")
        constant(value=" ")
        constant(value="\n")
}

#Template for Log hierarchy to build
template (name="RemoteStore" type="string" string="/var/log/epac_syslog/%HOSTNAME%/%PROGRAMNAME%.log")

#Local Logging with templating
kern.*                                                  action(type="omfile"  file="/var/log/kern.log" template="FileFormat")
*.info;mail.none;authpriv.none;cron.none                action(type="omfile"  file="/var/log/messages" template="FileFormat")
authpriv.*                                              action(type="omfile"  file="/var/log/secure" template="FileFormat")
mail.*                                                  action(type="omfile"  file="/var/log/maillog" template="FileFormat")
cron.*                                                  action(type="omfile"  file="/var/log/cron" template="FileFormat")
daemon.*                                                action(type="omfile"  file="/var/log/daemon.log" template="FileFormat")
syslog.*                                                action(type="omfile"  file="/var/log/syslog.log" template="FileFormat")
user.*                                                  action(type="omfile"  file="/var/log/user.log" template="FileFormat")
*.emerg                                                 :omusrmsg:*
uucp,news.crit                                          action(type="omfile"  file="/var/log/spooler" template="FileFormat")
local7.*                                                action(type="omfile"  file="/var/log/boot.log" template="FileFormat")



*.*  :omrelp:10.0.20.30:2514
#Reception of all logs following templates from servers
*.* ?RemoteStore;FileFormat
```